# How can I show a few progress bars one by one?

Tags: android, android-progressbar, timertask

I have to do something like this:

- Iterate between a few records of an arraylist.
- Show progressdialog for one record
- Move to next record
- and so on.

I am facing issues in showing progress dialog inside a for loop.

I have tried many variations of TimerTask and run. Here is my latest code of the sample demo application.

```
//In function of showing progress
for (int i = 0; i < myInfo.size() ; i++){
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ProgressTask(timer), 1000, 1000);
}

//Here is the ProgressTask
public class ProgressTask extends TimerTask {
    Timer timer;
    public ProgressTask (Timer timer){
        this.timer = timer;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        progressStatus = progressStatus + 10;
        progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
        if (progressStatus == 100) {
            timer.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

Result is: I just see the progress dialog for first record. Though it executes for loop for all the records, I have made some mistake in scheduling task or my run thread or timer. Can someone help me with the mistake in my code?

Edit:

[Here](https://pastebin.com/pAQvA7Pq) is the whole Activity's code if that helps.

Comment: Your problem isn't in this part of the code. Please provide the entire code where you show the `progressBar`

Comment: @jonathanrz Check complete code: https://pastebin.com/pAQvA7Pq

Comment: @Ana you can use an [Iterator](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Iterator) to manually loop over an List

Comment: @akaki no use. Tried but got a crash without any exception / logcat logs. And with iterator, progress dialog isn't shown at all

Comment: @Ana show your xml for MyActivity as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your progresstask executed simultaneously so you get only one progress. So adjust your delay to execute one by one.

Try this

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++){
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ProgressTask(timer),  i * 1000, 1000);
    }

 public class ProgressTask extends TimerTask {
    Timer timer;
    public ProgressTask (Timer timer){
        this.timer = timer;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        progressStatus = progressStatus + 10;
        progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
        timer.cancel(); //Cancel timer all time bcoz you create new timer everytime.

    }

}
```

Comment: just this didn't help. Had issues with timer.cancel(). Finally took help of timer[] in addition to your solution. Thanks for help.

Comment: Welcome gald to help..!